# Discord.py - {ctx.command} no showing entered command

Tags: python, discord.py

So, I'm new to discord.py and I'm trying to implement an error handling system that would show commandnotfound , missingrequiredarguments and etc in the terminal. And the problem is that I want it to show the entered command that wasn't recognized by writing `print("Command '{ctx.command}' Not Found")` but instead it just outputs `Command '{ctx.command}' Not Found` instead of `Command 'test' Not Found`. Any help would be appreciated!

My Code:

```
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.errors.CommandNotFound):
        print("Command '{ctx.command}' Not Found\n")
    
    if isinstance(error, commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument):
        print("Command '{ctx}.command' Has Missing Required Arguments\n")
    
    if isinstance(error, commands.errors.NoPrivateMessage):
        try:
            print("Command '{ctx.command}' Cannot Be Used In Private Messages")
        except discord.HTTPException:
            print("Command '{ctx.command}' Cannot Be Used In Private Messages (With HTTPExeption)")
    
    if isinstance(error, commands.errors.DisabledCommand):
        print("Command '{ctx.command}' Has Been Disabled")
    
    elif isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        if ctx.command.qualified_name == 'tag list':  
            print("Command '{ctx.command}' Defined An Invalid Member")

    else:
        print("Other Error")
```

Expected Results:

```
Command 'test' Has Missing Required Arguments
Command 'test' Cannot Be Used In Private Messages
Command 'test' Cannot Be Used In Private Messages (With HTTPExeption)
Command 'test' Has Been Disabled
Command 'test' Defined An Invalid Member
```

Actual Results:

```
Command '{ctx.command}' Has Missing Required Arguments
Command '{ctx.command}' Cannot Be Used In Private Messages
Command '{ctx.command}' Cannot Be Used In Private Messages (With HTTPExeption)
Command '{ctx.command}' Has Been Disabled
Command '{ctx.command}' Defined An Invalid Member
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a typo. You forgot `f` before each "", all `print()` functions should look like this if you use {}:

```
print(f"Command '{ctx.command}' Not Found\n")
```

Add the `f` before each "" in all the print functions and your problem will be sloved!!

Comment: Thanks, I think that worked! But when I run the code, instead of the command it says 'None'. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Sorry but i don't know, I searched on the internet but i didn't find anything. Sorry. Whenever your error is now ctx.command that returns None, i don't know why. You could just add error: the command cannot be used in DM without command name.